# Flutter unable to catch PlatformException while attempting firebase auth with googleSingIn

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-authentication

I have just started using flutter, I am trying to implement firebase signing in using googleAuth and it shows these errors below:

[image]

Comment: Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do NOT include images in your questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 2):

I have also recently faced this error and, I have found out that the `.catchError()` callback wasn't being called in the debug mode (which is when you click the `Run->Start Debugging` button in VSCode).

However, when you type in flutter run -d , then, the `.catchError()` method gets called back as it is not in debug mode.

To get your preferred simulator's code paste this line of code in the terminal:

```
instruments -s devices
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try pasting this:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

The  `.catchError()` method will get called unlike before and the code inside that will get executed as expected!

Additionally, the app won't crash anymore with a `PlatformException()` and instead you will get a log like this one:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

I have been facing this problem in Google Sign In too, in which the `.catchError()` was not being called!

In conclusion, if you have some error with handling errors in Firebase Authentication, you should first try to first run in through the terminal. Thanks, and I hope this helps!

Comment: :) Glad this helped you

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.
Follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18312

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19598

Comment: those solutions are usless! i've implemented all of them but no result

Comment: It's an open issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do trick by use Future Object

by example i want to use PhoneAuth and check **Code** write by user is true or not 
so the problem is cant catch the the exception come after user put **wrong** code

try this code
first declare the async method like this

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _signInWithCode(String code) async {
    AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationID, smsCode: code);
    try {
      AuthResult result = await mAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      FirebaseUser currentUser = await mAuth.currentUser();
      if (currentUser != null && result.user.uid == currentUser.uid) {
        return currentUser;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (exp) {}

    return null;
  }
```

**so if exp thrown the value come is null**

and some where in my code after user submit code use this code

```
FirebaseUser user = await _signInWithCode(code);

if (user != null)
      debugPrint("true input code");
    else {
      debugPrint("WRONNNG input code");
      setState(() {
        isValidCode = false;
      });
    }
```